# MySQL: Limit access to subset of records for each user

Tags: mysql, limit, records

We are using several tables that look roughly like this:

```
| ID  | DepartmentId | Data |
| 1   | 1            | ...  |
| 2   | 1            | ...  |
| 3   | 2            | ...  |
| 4   | 3            | ...  |
| 5   | 2            | ...  |
```

We have about 200 MySQL users, each of which is associated with one or more departments (via a simple Username/DepartmentId table)
We would like to limit the access (SELECT, UPDATE) to only the correct subset of the records for each user.

For example, a

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable
```

by user "Bob" who is associated with departments 1 and 3 should return records 1, 2 and 4. 
The same query for user "Alice", associated with department 1, should only return records 1 and 2.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You gotta do it from the application side. And it is pretty easy, actually.

Comment: When you say Mysql users, are you talking MySQL users listed in the mysql.user table you connect to the DB with or 'users' in a table called something like 'User' in your application

Comment: I mean actual MySQL users. We let MySQL handle user privileges as much as possible. This way, users can only log in to our application if they can actually connect to and access the database(s).

Comment: @ErikvdW  see you want want them to be able to an admin tool like sequel pro or phpmyadmin to log in directly and use the tables.  Also, I'll modify  my answer show how to add the department mapping table you'll need since it's not row to user, but row to dept.  The logic is still basically the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL does not have row based permissions.  The best you could do is construct views to  show certain records.  A simple way would be to add a mapping table with the mysql user names to department id's that they have access to and have the view select on that mapping table joined to the original where limited to the current requesting user. You can use `CURRENT_USER()` to get the current mysql user.

Then limit the users to the view, not the original table.

Here's a breakdown of the steps:

```
   CREATE TABLE `mysqluser_dept` (
     `mysqluser` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     `DepartmentId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       PRIMARY KEY (`mysqluser`,`DepartmentId`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW filtered_view AS 
           SELECT o.* FROM original_table o 
               JOIN mysqluser_dept m on m.DepartmentId = o.DepartmentId
                    WHERE m.mysqluser = current_user() GROUP by o.id;
```

You can limit the `select o.*` in the view as needed to a specific set of fields if you don't want to show all the columns of the original table.  Now populate the mapping table of mysqlusers to departmet column as needed.  The Current user returns exact user, so use full user string ( username@localhost, username@%, etc...) or change the view to chop off the host in the comparison.

Now a user can access the filtered_view and only see the rows they have access to by department.  Bonus: since this is many-to-many, you can have people in multiple departments if needed--the group by on the primary key of the original table avoids duplicate records.

You'll probably also want to lock down permissions to the mapping table mysqluser_department.

Comment: Although this isn't exactly the solution (don't want to directly limit each record to a specific user, but via a departments key), it does help me a lot. I hadn't thought of using a view using current_user(). I had considered creating temporary views on login for each user, but this is much more simple. Thanks!

Comment: +1.
Also, I realize this post is from more than 5 years ago, but I have a question: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like using the INVOKER security option would require the restricted user to have select permission on the underlying tables. Is there any reason for choosing INVOKER? Wouldn't it be preferable to use DEFINER security and the USER() function?

Comment: @favq, I read your comment only after a couple of hours trying out Ray's approach using DEFINER security instead of INVOKER. Then I suddenly see what I have been missing: In the where statement I didn't change Current_user() to User(). I always got blank results because the where statement always return false hahaha. Thanks for your great point.